# Application crashes only on android 4.4.2

Tags: android, crash, android-4.4-kitkat

I have an android application published in google play store. I have received few crash reports for it on android version 4.4.2. Application is working perfectly fine on lower android versions. I am unable to replicate this issue on android emulator.

Following is the stack trace of crashes reported on play store,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.bugsense.trace.Utils.manageUid(Unknown Source)
    at com.bugsense.trace.BugSenseHandler$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
```

Has anyone encountered similar issue? What can be the possible reason for this behaviour?

**NOTE:**
I have went through few similar questions on stackoverflow but none of them seemed to help me.

Comment: Is that the *full* stack trace? I would take this up with [BugSense](https://www.bugsense.com/) and ask why this exception is thrown

Comment: yes this is what I got in crash reports at play store. Issue is not even getting replicated on android 4.4 emulator :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/bishopmatthew/HackerNews/pull/34 here you can find workaround:

```
Solution:
Remove 'bugsense3.2.3.jar' from the project's libraries, and instead
include 'bugsense-3.5.jar'.
```

Comment: I went through this link but there is no `bugsense3.2.3.jar` in my projects library. I am not using `Bugsense`.

Comment: Maybe some library project, that are you using, has bugsense.jar, hasn't it?

Comment: I am only using `ActionBarSherlock`. Got to check if it uses bugsense.

Comment: It is Airpush SDK that is using bugsense. Thank you!

Comment: @user2235057 can you explain how you solved this error? i'm having the same problem and i think it's also related to Airpush SDK.. thanks in advance..

Comment: @NickolaiAstashonok thank you for your response.. but i don't have bugsense library in my project libs.. but i think the problem is some how related to airbush sdk

Comment: @NickolaiAstashonok yes, i have.. how do i replace the bugsense library in them.. do i have to remove them??

Comment: Nope, you just should replace bugsense jar in projects